# How do I scrape the names of founders of a company along with their respective info (i.e. gender, education, etc.) ??? Crunchbase

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I've been working on this code for a while and now need to pull more information concerning a company's founding team: like who are the founder(s), the founder(s) gender(s), their educational background (alma mater), and the size of the team at the company.

(this is all on crunchbase)...I also need to pull this info for every company listed on the EV industry page.

I'm pretty good with figuring out the xpaths of these webpage elements, however, Im having trouble  with storing the info (from above) in a dataframe while navigating the textlinks...not to mention doing it all in a nested loop because I need to scrape the info for every EV company...  Any help???

```
#imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import pandas as pd
import time

#driver path
PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#access crunchbase ui
driver.get("https://www.crunchbase.com/search/organizations/field/organization.companies/categories/electric-vehicle")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.title)

    
time.sleep(3)
   
#await element location

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ('//a[@aria-label="Next"][@aria-disabled="false"][@type="button"]'))))
    
#next page
page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/search/page-layout/div/div/form/div[2]/results/div/div/div[1]/div/results-info/h3/a[2]')

company_list = [] ###create dictionary
   
counter = 0
for _ in range(2):
    if counter == 1:
        break
    counter += 1
    
    if page.is_displayed():
        
        time.sleep(25)
        
        #webscrape through iterations
        all_rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("grid-row")
                                                      
        for row in all_rows:
            companyname = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="identifier-label"]')
            companyname.click()
            time.sleep(25) 
            company=driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="profile-name"]')
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(company).perform()
            company_list.append(company)
        print("next")
        page.click()
    
    
#create dataframe    
df = pd.DataFrame(company_list)
```

Comment: At which step are you stuck? What are the manual steps required to repro the issue? Do you have demo creds for login?

Comment: @DebanjanB Im stuck when the program opens the first company profile page from the EV list. The company name won't store in company_list, and I cant scroll down to scrape founders info (name), then click into each founder and get gender, education, etc..... then finally do it all again for the following companies.  ***don't need the creds tbh - free version gives you acces to the first page of ev companies. I'd just omit the login block of code***

Comment: @DebanjanB just deleted the log in code-- wasnt needed

Comment: The organization name _Bird_ is reflected in the first page itself, why do you want to `companyname.click()`? PS: `//*[@class="profile-name"]` refers to _Bird_ only

Comment: @DebanjanB because i didn't know how to store that info edit: I guess a better question would be how to store data from webpage elements on different pages ???

Comment: @furas any ideas ???

Comment: Let me follow up. Did you want to click Bird, Rivian, Nio, Tesla, Zoomo and etc. Cause //a[@class='component--field-formatter field-type-identifier link-accent ng-star-inserted'] would get all the elements you need and than using .get_attribute('title') would get the names and .get_attribute('href') would allow you to get the list of urls you can go to.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan just posted an updated version of the code...head to that post ?